# How to solve snap install permission denied on RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel7, clangd, snap

I was following [this guide](https://snapcraft.io/install/clangd/rhel#install) to install clangd.

After installing snap smoothly, I tried to install clangd, but the following error occurred.

```
$ sudo snap install clangd --classic
error: cannot add authorization: open /[home directory]/.snap/auth.json: permission denied
```

OS is RHEL 7.

If anyone knows about that issue please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ sudo SNAPD_AUTH_DATA_FILENAME=/nonexistent snap install clangd --classic
```